# SQL row won't delete. Throws no error

Tags: python, sql, mariadb

I have a row in my DB that I can't delete.  I ran this SQL in python and got this error:

```
MariaDB [cryptotrader2]> INSERT INTO `trades` VALUES("gemini",2465337307,17317.010000,0.008923,1513178949);
    ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'gemini-2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Which is strange since I am not affecting that entry. I found that there was only one row where exchange='gemini' and I can't delete it or add other entries where exchange='gemini'.  Or at least not from my python program.  I did manage to make a manual entry as you can see below.  I am not having problems with entries with other exchange names, it's just gemini.

```
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 84
Server version: 10.0.30-MariaDB-0+deb8u1 (Debian)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [cryptotrader2]> select * from trades where exchange='gemini'
    ->
    -> ;
+----------+------------+----------+------------+------------+
| exchange | trade_id   | price    | volume     | timestamp  |
+----------+------------+----------+------------+------------+
| gemini   | 2147483647 | 17395.80 | 0.06573300 | 1513178007 |
+----------+------------+----------+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [cryptotrader2]> delete from trades where exchange='gemini';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [cryptotrader2]> select * from trades where exchange='gemini';
+----------+------------+----------+------------+------------+
| exchange | trade_id   | price    | volume     | timestamp  |
+----------+------------+----------+------------+------------+
| gemini   | 2147483647 | 17385.33 | 0.07917300 | 1513178234 |
+----------+------------+----------+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [cryptotrader2]> insert into trades values ('gemini',1234564560,17000,1,1513178235);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [cryptotrader2]> select * from trades where exchange='gemini';          +----------+------------+----------+------------+------------+
| exchange | trade_id   | price    | volume     | timestamp  |
+----------+------------+----------+------------+------------+
| gemini   | 1234564560 | 17000.00 | 1.00000000 | 1513178235 |
| gemini   | 2147483647 | 17385.33 | 0.07917300 | 1513178234 |
+----------+------------+----------+------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [cryptotrader2]> delete from trades where exchange='gemini';            Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [cryptotrader2]> select * from trades where exchange='gemini';
+----------+------------+----------+------------+------------+
| exchange | trade_id   | price    | volume     | timestamp  |
+----------+------------+----------+------------+------------+
| gemini   | 2147483647 | 17390.16 | 0.87946700 | 1513178350 |
+----------+------------+----------+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE trades`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clearly being deleted but somewhere you have a upsert creating an entry for gemini. See how the price, volume and timestamp change.

I should say that the reason for the error is INT has a maximum signed value of 2147483647. Your attempt at trying to insert a higher value(2465337307) apparently gets truncated down to the max which in this case is true, you already have an entry for gemini, 2147483647. Try inserting

```
    INSERT INTO `trades` VALUES("gemini",2147483646,17317.010000,0.008923,1513178949);
```

using your python program.

Comment: You may want to also think about making trade_id bigint